# heatmap of values grouped by time - seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, heatmap

I'm plotting the counts of a variable grouped by time as a heatmap. However, when including both hour and minute, the counts are quite low so the resulting heatmap doesn't really provide any real insight. Is it possible to group the counts in a bigger block of time? I'm hoping to test some different periods (5, 10 mins).

I'm also hoping to plot time on the x-axis. Similar to the output attached.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

start = datetime(1900,1,1,10,0,0)
end = datetime(1900,1,1,13,0,0)

seconds = (end - start).total_seconds()

step = timedelta(minutes = 1)

array = []
for i in range(0, int(seconds), int(step.total_seconds())):
    array.append(start + timedelta(seconds=i))

array = [i.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M%:%S') for i in array]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(array).rename(columns = {0:'Time'})
df2['Count'] = np.random.uniform(0.0, 0.5, size = len(df2))
df2['Count'] = df2['Count'].round(1)

df2['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Time'])
df2['Hour'] = df2['Time'].dt.hour
df2['Min'] = df2['Time'].dt.minute

g = df2.groupby(['Hour','Min','Count'])

count_df = g['Count'].nunique().unstack()

count_df.fillna(0, inplace = True)

sns.heatmap(count_df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deal with such cases, I think it would be easy to use data downsampling. It is also easy to change the thresholds. The axis labels in the output graph will need to be modified, but we recommend this method.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

start = datetime(1900,1,1,10,0,0)
end = datetime(1900,1,1,13,0,0)

seconds = (end - start).total_seconds()

step = timedelta(minutes = 1)

array = []
for i in range(0, int(seconds), int(step.total_seconds())):
    array.append(start + timedelta(seconds=i))

array = [i.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for i in array]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(array).rename(columns = {0:'Time'})
df2['Count'] = np.random.uniform(0.0, 0.5, size = len(df2))
df2['Count'] = df2['Count'].round(1)

df2['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Time'])
df2['Hour'] = df2['Time'].dt.hour
df2['Min'] = df2['Time'].dt.minute

df2.set_index('Time', inplace=True)
count_df = df2.resample('10min')['Count'].value_counts().unstack()
count_df.fillna(0, inplace = True)

sns.heatmap(count_df.T)
```

[image]

Comment: A much better solution. Didn't know you could do that with resample :)

Comment: This is nice. Is it possible to swap axes though. With `Time` on the x-axis?

Comment: You can use `sns.heatmap(count_df.T)` to swap the axes.

Comment: Cheers. Does this make the y-axis upside down though?

Comment: Does upside down mean the label start point of xticks?

Comment: The values read from 0.5 to 0. Rather than starting at 0.

Comment: I noticed your comment. I can deal with this now. `ax = sns.heatmap(count_df.T);ax.invert_yaxis()`

Answer (score 1):

The way you could achieve this is by creating a column with numbers that have repeating elements for the number of minutes.
For example:

```
minutes = 3
x = [0,1,2]
np.repeat(x, repeats=minutes, axis=0)
>>>> [0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2]
```

and then group your data using this column.

So your code would look like:

```
...
minutes = 5
x = [i for i in range(int(df2.shape[0]/5))]
df2['group'] = np.repeat(x, repeats=minutes, axis=0)

g = df2.groupby(['Min', 'Count'])

count_df = g['Count'].nunique().unstack()

count_df.fillna(0, inplace = True)
```